# SQL How to sort child rows based on an "order" field?

Tags: sql

I guess it's been a while since I've written SQL and I'm stumped by this seemingly trivial requirement: I want to join a parent and a child table together and order the child columns by a field named "order" in the child table.

Assume you have a `question` table and a `question_answer` table:

```
question ( question_id, question_text )
question_answer ( answer_id, question_id, answer_text, display_order )
```

So for each question there can be multiple answers, and each answer will have a `display_order` field.

Here's how some data might look:

```
question
--------
1, "How much milk should I add""
2, "About how fast was he going?"

question_answer
---------------

1, 1, "A little", 0
2, 1, "Moderate", 1
3, 1, "A lot", 2
4, 2, "Pretty slow", 0
5, 2, "Average", 1
6, 2, "Like a bat out of hell", 2
```

So the desired outcome when joining `question` and `question_answer` would show the question and each of its answer, but those answers would be in the `display_order` given, within the answers for a question.

A simple query such as

```
select
    q.question_text,
    qa.answer_text
from
    question q,
    question_answer qa
where
    q.question_id = qa.question_id
order by
    qa.display_order
```

sorts all the rows in the result set by `display_order`, instead of ordering just each group of answers for a question by their `display_order`

Michael

Comment: Pl try adding q.question_id to the order by clause i.e. `order by q.question_id, qa.display_order `

Comment: Returning `question` data repeated for each `question_answer` is suboptimal (as you're sending the same data multiple times over the network connection). Consider executing two queries in a batch statement that gets questions separately from answers, yet because it's a batch statement there won't be excessive chatter or latency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order by q.question_id, qa.display_order`

Comment: Damn, you beat me by ~20 seconds. Guess I'll have to be faster next time :P

Answer (score 2):

You need two keys in the `order by`:

```
select q.question_text, qa.answer_text
from question q join
     question_answer qa
     on q.question_id = qa.question_id
order by q.question_id, qa.display_order;
```

Note that you should learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by

1. q.question_id
2. qa.display_order

You can stick as many columns in the order by clause as you wat.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query. This will sort first by question_id and then by display order.

```
select
  q.question_text,
  qa.answer_text
from
  question q, question_answer qa
where
  q.question_id = qa.question_id
order by
  q.question_id, qa.display_order
```